# Iterate over rows of QTableView

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qstandarditemmodel

I have a QTableView showing the children of a specific QModelIndex in my model (which has hierarchical data, which the table cannot of course show). I want to be able to iterate over all items in the table view, i.e. all children of the rootIndex. How can I efficiently do this? I have a reference to the parent index with table.rootIndex(), however I don't see any way of iterating over the children of an index without iterating over the whole entire model, which just seems wrong.

Is this a job for a QSortFilterProxyModel to install a sub-set of the model in the table? Does what I just said even make sense?!

Here's a quick sample to get up and running

```
class Sample(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
    super(Sample, self).__init__()
        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)

        parent_index1 = QtGui.QStandardItemModel("Parent1")
        model.appendRow(parent_index1)

        parent_index2 = QtGui.QStandardItemModel("Parent2")
        model.appendRow(parent_index2)

        one = QtGui.QStandardItem("One")
        two = QtGui.QStandardItem("Two")
        three = QtGui.QStandardItem("Three")

        parent_index1.appendRows([one, two, three])

        table = QtGui.QTableView(self)
        table.setModel(model)
        table.setRootIndex(model.index(0,0))

        # okay now how would I loop over all 'visible' rows in the table? (children of parent_index1)
```

Comment: @eyllanesc you are the master of tag editing, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I feel dumb, I figured it out. Forgot that `model.index()` allows you to specify a parent... I suppose some other poor soul out there might get as confused as I just was so here you go:

```
for row in range(self.model.rowCount(self.table.rootIndex())):
    child_index = self.model.index(row, 0, self.table.rootIndex())) # for column 0
```

Comment: I guess I'm a poor soul because I have run into this issue and though this solution worked for you, I do not find this helpful or universal. There has to be a better way to iterate through the rows of a QTableView

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this answer is helpful to the other poor souls.

A QTableView is just a view of a model. The key is that you should be iterating over the model, not the view. This goes over each row in the QTableView's model and over each column within each row. You can modify as needed.

```
for r in range(tableView.model().rowCount()):
   for c in range(tableView.model().columnCount()):
      index = self.invoiceTbl.model().index(r, c)
```